# Given an itinerary receipt from a travel agent, how do I find out the fare conditions of the ticket?

Tags: usa, tickets, legal

For the first time in a long time, I traveled on a ticket that was purchased (in the US) at a travel agent. Our travel party got itinerary receipts, not e-tickets. At the end of the itinerary receipt, there was a brief description of fare restrictions; but there was no notice of terms incorporated by reference, as I'd always seen with my past e-tickets.

My understanding of Federal regulations is that whatever document you get that embodies the contract of carriage is supposed to have this notice of terms being incorporated by reference. I'm in a dispute now with the airline about fees, so this technicality is relevant.

Do itinerary receipts typically not have this notice? If so, what's the argument that airlines make to say that they are still complying with Federal regulations?

Comment: Is the ticket part of a package/tour/holiday?

Comment: No, not part of a package. Our travel agent booked our accommodations separately from our air transportation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your agent has printed out the receipts against a reservation system (like amadeus, galileo, etc.) which is typical for agents.

They should have also provided you with a link where you can view your itinerary - something like a link to [viewtrip.com](https://www.viewtrip.com) which is Galileo's customer facing portal; or [checkmytrip.com](https://www.checkmytrip.com) the equivalent for Amadeus.

In both of these places, or on the paper reservation - you should have your PNR number.

You can use this at the airline's website to retrieve your booking and your e-ticket receipt.

At the bottom of the e-ticket receipt, you should see the terms and carriage contract and any specific restrictions on your ticket class/type.

Most airlines have their contract of carriage available online (for example, [here is the page from united](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/contract.aspx) which also links to the terms for their partner airlines), you can also research there.

However, I am confident that at your e-ticket receipt you should see the correct *applicable* terms for that ticket/fare class, etc.